# Enter a URL in input text and open it in current page

Tags: javascript, html, url, web

I'm new to HTML and I need an HTML code that allows user to enter a URL in a text box and will redirect him/her to the URL he has entered after clicking on a button

The best solution would be a HTML code.

I was trying this code:

```
<form method=get action="http://" target=_blank><input type=text><input type=submit value="Go"></form>
```

Unfortunately, I am stuck here, so my question is: how should I continue this task?

Comment: you can start by attempting to write this html

Comment: I already tried and I've already searched the internet about this

Comment: Don't think it's possible in full html since the URL is variable.

Comment: then you should have posted what you tried, we don't supply free code and we discourage such requests

Comment: Doubt you even made an attempt as you provide no code and this is about as easy of JS as there is.

Comment: What you've used is form tag with action attribute which would require server side programming to process the data and then give output. If you want just plain HTML i.e. client side, the proposed answer is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<input id="txt" name="order" type="text">
<input id='btn' type="submit" value="submit"
onclick="location.href=document.getElementById('txt').value" >
```

Comment: Thanks but it is used to go to a file in the directory where is the HTML archive with the code.

Comment: Its better you post your code what you have tried.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question

Comment: Your code does work! When I put "google.com" it didn't worked, but it works when I put "http://google.com/". Thank you very much for your contribution!

Comment: you may change the value to "location.href='http://'+document.getElementById('txt').value"

Comment: Thanks, but I've done this a few minutes ago

Comment: Mark it as answer if it helped.